# Is there any way to hide some chars from a string?

Tags: java, android, string

For example I have `Hello123456` string and I want to show it as just `Hello` in a TextView.

I need those numbers in my code and I can't erase them.

**EDIT:**

All answer are providing a way that I erase the numbers and then set it to textview, But I want them to be there.

I get the "hello" part from user and I add the number part to it and this will be the name of a listview Item. but I want to show just the hello part in listview and also if I checked if that listview clicked item ends with "123456" it returns true.

Comment: Do you need to erase numbers only?

Comment: try `System.out.println("Hello123456".replaceAll("\\d+", ""));`

Comment: if you know the length of part of string that you want then you can use StringBuilder builder;
  builder.substring(start, end)

Comment: Btw, you'll create a temporary string, better said, a new String, even if you do not want to :) Strings are inmutable.

Comment: just have two textViews, one with the proper data and one without,  I am sure you can hide the one with all the data.

Comment: By textview I mean listview item name.

Comment: You can assign the original text to the `tag`, and display the modified text, check updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `TextView` can have a `tag` attached to it i.e. some object that is stored as extra data to the view itself. Check out the documentation here:

- [View.setTag(Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))

In your case, you can assign the "Hello" to the displayed text (using the method below), and set the `tag` to the full text.

```
textView.setText(getDisplayText(helloString));
textView.setTag("TAG", helloString);
```

When the user clicks on your view, you can get the tag from the view and do what you need with it.

This way, there is more data stored than what you see.

---

*(original answer before the edit)*

How about a method that does what you need:

```
private String getDisplayText(String input)
{
    return input.substring(0, 5);
}
```

And then just use that method when you set the value of your `TextView`.

```
textView.setText(getDisplayText(helloString));
```

Comment: Tag is the answer. Thanks so much :).

Answer (score 1):

```
 I want to show it as just "Hello" in a TextView.
```

Then just put `Hello` in your `TextView` without cutting your string or create an `temporary string` to hold the `"Hello"` String.

If your string is like this `"HELLOHI12345"` then you need a **regex** to eliminate all the number string within it.

**sample:**

```
textview.setText(s.replaceAll("[0-9]+", ""));
```

Also take note that string are **immutable** so the original String wont get replaced after executing `replaceAll`

Comment: @SaDeGH_F post your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Use this dude ! :) You can use contextDescription to access the actual text

```
    textView.setText(yourText.replaceAll("[0-9]",""));
    textView.setContentDescription(yourText);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str = ((TextView) v.getContentDescription()).toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: good idea, but on a phone that has been set up for Accessibility, the original text might be read out to the user - that is the idea behind the content description. So to a blind person, this will be as if we are not removing the numbers at all.

Answer (score 0):

use `\\w+` regex with `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes. This will also work if you don't know the String length. The String can be `hello123` or `olo123`

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to hide the characters in a string. You have to solve your problem in a different way. My suggestion is to implement a separate class which contains the string:

I would write an class which contains the string. Then add two methods to this class which returns the string for display and for internal use. E.g.

```
class DataObject {

    private String data;

    public String forTextView() {
      //code from one of the answers above, may be the regex version
    }

    public Stringg getStringWithNumbers() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

This allows you to show the string without the numbers and still have them ready when you use them.